# List Orderby property from nullable object

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a collection of objectAs in a list.  There is an objectB within the objectA.  I want to sort the list by objectB.Prop1 but i keep getting a null reference when it sorts through the list.
This is what I have in my code:

```
data.OrderBy(c =>c.obj.Name);
```

I know I'm getting the null reference because some of the items have `obj` null.  I have thought of separating the list into two: one with null obj, and one that has an object for obj then sort, then concat afterwards. But I am wondering if there is a better way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this help?

```
data.OrderBy(c => c.obj != null? c.obj.Name : "");
```